# Retrofit2 POST request with Body

Tags: android, retrofit

I need make POST request with parameters "guid=1" in Body. i use Retrofit2

I try :

```
@POST("/api/1/model")
Call<ApiModelJson> getPostClub(@Body User body);
```

User Class:

```
public class User {
     @SerializedName("guid")
     String guid;
public User(String guid ) {
     this.guid = guid;
```

}

MailActivity:

```
User user =new User ("1");
Call<ApiModelJson> call = service.getPostClub(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiModelJson>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<ApiModelJson> response) {
}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

How make this request?

Answer (score 1):

you have to call `call.enqueue`, providing an instance of `Callback< ApiModelJson>`, where you will get the response. `enqueue` executes your backend call asynchronously. You can read more about `call.enqueue` [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/)

Answer (score 0):

With code below, you can make the request synchronously:

```
ApiModelJson responseBody = call.execute();
```

If you want it to be asynchronous:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ApiModelJson>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<ApiModelJson> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    }
});
```

Comment: Server return error  response = {"body":{"model":[]},"datetime":1446130789,"type":"error"}